# How do you read Tensorboard files programmatically?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

How can you write a python script to read Tensorboard log files, extracting the loss and accuracy and other numerical data, without launching the GUI `tensorboard --logdir=...`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use TensorBoard's Python classes or script to extract the data:

[How can I export data from TensorBoard?](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard#how-can-i-export-data-from-tensorboard)

> If you'd like to export data to visualize elsewhere (e.g. iPython Notebook), that's possible too. You can directly depend on the underlying classes that TensorBoard uses for loading data: `python/summary/event_accumulator.py` (for loading data from a single run) or `python/summary/event_multiplexer.py` (for loading data from multiple runs, and keeping it organized). These classes load groups of event files, discard data that was "orphaned" by TensorFlow crashes, and organize the data by tag.
>
> As another option, there is a script (`tensorboard/scripts/serialize_tensorboard.py`) which will load a logdir just like TensorBoard does, but write all of the data out to disk as json instead of starting a server. This script is setup to make "fake TensorBoard backends" for testing, so it is a bit rough around the edges.

Using [`EventAccumulator`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/summary/event_accumulator.py#L107):

```
# In [1]: from tensorflow.python.summary import event_accumulator  # deprecated
In [1]: from tensorboard.backend.event_processing import event_accumulator

In [2]: ea = event_accumulator.EventAccumulator('events.out.tfevents.x.ip-x-x-x-x',
   ...:  size_guidance={ # see below regarding this argument
   ...:      event_accumulator.COMPRESSED_HISTOGRAMS: 500,
   ...:      event_accumulator.IMAGES: 4,
   ...:      event_accumulator.AUDIO: 4,
   ...:      event_accumulator.SCALARS: 0,
   ...:      event_accumulator.HISTOGRAMS: 1,
   ...:  })

In [3]: ea.Reload() # loads events from file
Out[3]: <tensorflow.python.summary.event_accumulator.EventAccumulator at 0x7fdbe5ff59e8>

In [4]: ea.Tags()
Out[4]: 
{'audio': [],
 'compressedHistograms': [],
 'graph': True,
 'histograms': [],
 'images': [],
 'run_metadata': [],
 'scalars': ['Loss', 'Epsilon', 'Learning_rate']}

In [5]: ea.Scalars('Loss')
Out[5]: 
[ScalarEvent(wall_time=1481232633.080754, step=1, value=1.6365480422973633),
 ScalarEvent(wall_time=1481232633.2001867, step=2, value=1.2162202596664429),
 ScalarEvent(wall_time=1481232633.3877788, step=3, value=1.4660096168518066),
 ScalarEvent(wall_time=1481232633.5749283, step=4, value=1.2405034303665161),
 ScalarEvent(wall_time=1481232633.7419815, step=5, value=0.897326648235321),
 ...]
```

[`size_guidance`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/summary/event_accumulator.py#L151):

```
size_guidance: Information on how much data the EventAccumulator should
  store in memory. The DEFAULT_SIZE_GUIDANCE tries not to store too much
  so as to avoid OOMing the client. The size_guidance should be a map
  from a `tagType` string to an integer representing the number of
  items to keep per tag for items of that `tagType`. If the size is 0,
  all events are stored.
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working example of what exactly to use in these scripts?

Comment: As of version 1.1.0 of Tensorflow, event_accumulator has been moved to tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorboard/backend/event_processing. To get the code to work in version 1.1.0 the import statement should be `from tensorflow.tensorboard.backend.event_processing import event_accumulator` [more info here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9532)

Comment: And as of 1.3 it has been moved from the TensorFlow repo to a dedicated TensorBoard repo. New home: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard.
Can be pip-installed as a standalone package, import statement is now: `from tensorboard.backend.event_processing import event_accumulator`

Comment: It seems the APIs have been changed and it doesn't work since `TensorFlow 1.1+`.

Comment: Just for further reference: I created a tool that aggregates multiple tensorboard summaries and saves the results to new tensorboard summaries or as `.csv` files. Have a look here: https://github.com/Spenhouet/tensorboard-aggregator

Answer (score 8):

To finish user1501961's answer, you can then just export the list of scalars to a csv file easily with pandas `pd.DataFrame(ea.Scalars('Loss)).to_csv('Loss.csv')`

Answer (score 4):

For anyone interested, I've adapted [user1501961](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1501961/user1501961)'s answer into a function for parsing tensorboard scalars into a dictionary of pandas dataframes:

```py
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing import event_accumulator
import pandas as pd


def parse_tensorboard(path, scalars):
    """returns a dictionary of pandas dataframes for each requested scalar"""
    ea = event_accumulator.EventAccumulator(
        path,
        size_guidance={event_accumulator.SCALARS: 0},
    )
    _absorb_print = ea.Reload()
    # make sure the scalars are in the event accumulator tags
    assert all(
        s in ea.Tags()["scalars"] for s in scalars
    ), "some scalars were not found in the event accumulator"
    return {k: pd.DataFrame(ea.Scalars(k)) for k in scalars}
```

Comment: Can confirm this works great!

Comment: It seems like the API has changed in TF2.x. Here, I had to replace ```ea.Tags()["scalars"]``` with ```ea.Tags()["tensors"]``` and ```ea.Scalars(k)``` with ```ea.Tensors(k)```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bash
    python << EOF | bat --color=always -pltsv
from contextlib import suppress
import sys
from time import gmtime, strftime

import pandas as pd
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing.event_file_loader import (
    EventFileLoader,
)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Step", "Value"])
df.index.name = "YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM"

for event in EventFileLoader("$1").Load():
    with suppress(IndexError):
        df.loc[strftime("%F %H:%M", gmtime(event.wall_time))] = [  # type: ignore
            event.step,  # type: ignore
            event.summary.value[0].tensor.float_val[0],  # type: ignore
        ]
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)  # type: ignore
df.Step = df.Step.astype(int)
df.to_csv(sys.stdout, "\t")
EOF
```

bat is optimal.

Comment: hey, your formatting is off. See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/9889508) for a guide on how to format your code in your answers