# Get CSV from Tensorflow summaries

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I have some very large tensorflow summaries. If these are plotted using tensorboard, I can download CSV files from them.

However, plotting these using tensorboard would take a very long time. I found in [the docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md) that there is a method for reading the summary directly in Python. This method is `summary_iterator` and can be used as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

for e in tf.train.summary_iterator(path to events file):
    print(e)
```

Can I use this method to create CSV files directly? If so, how can I do this? This would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way of doing it would be like this:

```
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing import event_accumulator      
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys

def create_csv(inpath, outpath):
    sg = {event_accumulator.COMPRESSED_HISTOGRAMS: 1,
          event_accumulator.IMAGES: 1,
          event_accumulator.AUDIO: 1,
          event_accumulator.SCALARS: 0,
          event_accumulator.HISTOGRAMS: 1}
    ea = event_accumulator.EventAccumulator(inpath, size_guidance=sg)
    ea.Reload()
    scalar_tags = ea.Tags()['scalars']
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=scalar_tags)
    for tag in scalar_tags:
        events = ea.Scalars(tag)
        scalars = np.array(map(lambda x: x.value, events))
        df.loc[:, tag] = scalars
    df.to_csv(outpath)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv
    inpath = args[1]
    outpath = args[2]
    create_csv(inpath, outpath)
```

Please note, this code will load the entire event file into memory, so best to run this on a cluster. For information about the `sg` argument of the `EventAccumulator`, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074688/how-do-you-read-tensorboard-files-programmatically).

An additional improvement might be to not only store the `value` of each scalar, but also the `step`.

*Note* The code snippet was updated for recent versions of `TF`.  **For TF < 1.1** use the following import instead:

```
from tensorflow.tensorboard.backend.event_processing import event_accumulator as eva
```

Comment: great idea!  btw as of TF 1.1 the package is `tensorboard.backend.event_processing import event_accumulator ` . I took the liberty to update your code accordingly