# Exporting tensorboard computation graph as Panda dataframe

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

There is a need to export a CNN computational graph from Tensorbaord as Panda dataframe.
I have looked at https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/dataframe_api and only training information is logged (because of defining a callback function during the training process).
Is there any way to log the network architecture & weights in the logs then extract it as a panda dataframe!

Comment: The last time I tried doing this using the source you mentioned, it didn;t go well. I found out that I couldn't use ExperimentFromDev(not so sure now) somehow. I instead manually read the TB log files.

Comment: I used the method of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074688/how-do-you-read-tensorboard-files-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

The last time I tried doing this using the source you mentioned, it didn't go well. I found out that I couldn't use the ExperimentFromDev(not so sure now) which was used in the tutorial. I instead manually read the TB log files using the method of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074688/how-do-you-read-tensorboard-files-programmatically) question. The second answer could be the solution in your case.

```
ea = event_accumulator.EventAccumulator('events.out.tfevents.x.ip-x-x-x-x',
  size_guidance={ # see below regarding this argument
      event_accumulator.COMPRESSED_HISTOGRAMS: 500,
      event_accumulator.IMAGES: 4,
      event_accumulator.AUDIO: 4,
      event_accumulator.SCALARS: 0,
      event_accumulator.HISTOGRAMS: 1,
})
pd.DataFrame(ea.Scalars('Loss)).to_csv('Loss.csv')
```