# Tensorboard: Accessing tensor-objects in the tags of event_accumulator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to access some data stored in a Tensorboard-file. I would prefer not opening it with the Tensorboard GUI in my browser but directly open it in a python-script to be able to do further calculations.

My current code:

```py
file = # here, filename is provided
ea = event_accumulator.EventAccumulator(event_file[0])
ea.Reload()
print(ea.Tags())
```

Now, my tags (*ea.Tags()*) are sth. like this:

```
{'histograms': [], 'scalars': [], 'tensors': ['observable1', 'observable2' ], ...}
```

First thing that's interesting is that my data of the observables are not saved in 'scalars' but in 'tensors'. How can I access these observables now?
I would expect that each of the two oberservables gives an array/ a list of values (that's what I'm interested in) and probably also some tensor-related data like shapes, datatype etc.

I've already tried out to access the tensors using

```
x=ea.Tensors("observable1")
print(x[0])
```

or similar, but I got stuck in there as the output is sth. like this:

```
TensorEvent(wall_time=1234567890.987654, step=123, tensor_proto=dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
}
tensor_content: "\123Y\123@"
)
```

and *x* seems to have a fixed length of 10 which was, in somehow, unexpected to me. Does somebody have an idea? All the explanations I found on the internet are dealing only about the scalars in a Tensorboard-file

Answer (score 1):

Provided that it has been previously written like

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
tensorboard_writer=SummaryWriter(log_dir=logpath)
tensorboard_writer.add_scalar("loss_val", loss, parameter)
```

this example will extract the score:

```
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing.event_accumulator import EventAccumulator
    
event_acc = EventAccumulator(logpath, size_guidance={"scalars": 0})
event_acc.Reload()

for scalar in event_acc.Tags()["scalars"]:
    w_times, step_nums, vals = zip(*event_acc.Scalars(scalar))
```

Perhaps writing the scalars wasn't successful?

Answer (score 0):

This post is fairly old, but posting here for future reference.

To access the `tensor_content` in `observable1`, for example, do

```py
x = ea.Tensors("observable1")[0].tensor_proto.tensor_content[0]
```

and `x` will contain the value you desire in binary form.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074688/how-do-you-read-tensorboard-files-programmatically), I changed

```
ea = event_accumulator.EventAccumulator(event_file[0])
```

to

```
ea = event_accumulator.EventAccumulator(
    event_file[0],
    size_guidance={event_accumulator.TENSORS: 0})
)
```

and I was able to get all (more than 10) logged values.