# Export tensorboard (with pytorch) data into csv with python

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

I have Tensorboard data and want it to download all of the csv files behind the data, but I could not find anything from the official [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html). From [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074688/how-do-you-read-tensorboard-files-programmatically), I found only this question which is 7 years old and also it's about TensorFlow while I am using PyTorch.

We can do this manually, as we can see in the screenshot, manually there is an option. I wonder if we can do that via code or it is not possible? As I have a lot of data to process.

[image]

Comment: I have found this script on GitHub that will convert a tensorboard event log to a CSV [script](https://github.com/theRealSuperMario/supermariopy/blob/master/scripts/tflogs2pandas.py)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the help of this [script](https://github.com/theRealSuperMario/supermariopy/blob/master/scripts/tflogs2pandas.py) Below is the shortest working code it gets all of the data in `dataframe` then you can play further.

```
import traceback
import pandas as pd
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing.event_accumulator import EventAccumulator

# Extraction function
def tflog2pandas(path):
    runlog_data = pd.DataFrame({"metric": [], "value": [], "step": []})
    try:
        event_acc = EventAccumulator(path)
        event_acc.Reload()
        tags = event_acc.Tags()["scalars"]
        for tag in tags:
            event_list = event_acc.Scalars(tag)
            values = list(map(lambda x: x.value, event_list))
            step = list(map(lambda x: x.step, event_list))
            r = {"metric": [tag] * len(step), "value": values, "step": step}
            r = pd.DataFrame(r)
            runlog_data = pd.concat([runlog_data, r])
    # Dirty catch of DataLossError
    except Exception:
        print("Event file possibly corrupt: {}".format(path))
        traceback.print_exc()
    return runlog_data
path="Run1" #folderpath
df=tflog2pandas(path)
#df=df[(df.metric != 'params/lr')&(df.metric != 'params/mm')&(df.metric != 'train/loss')] #delete the mentioned rows
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: Note that the `EventAccumulator` limits the number of events stored in memory by default. Therefore, your `event_list` may not contain every event within the file. Pass the `size_guidance={"scalars": 0}` argument to the constructor to lift the limit for the scalar data.

Comment: In anyone needs to extend this to get time, just modify/add the lines (1)
`runlog_data = pd.DataFrame({"metric": [], "value": [], "step": [], "wall_time": []})` (2)
`wall_time = list(map(lambda x: x.wall_time, event_list))` (3)
`r = {"metric": [tag] * len(step), "value": values, "step": step, "wall_time": wall_time}`