# Extracting data from inference profiling in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Is it possible to extract the actual data collected by tensorboard and used in plotting the visual below during [inference profiling](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/tensorboard)?
[image]

The inference profiling part is of particular interest because it requires the *profile plugin*; although it is possible to [extract scalars programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074688/how-do-you-read-tensorboard-files-programmatically), I have not found a way to access the profiler stats in a programmatic way.

In large test cases, it would be good to be able to analyze the data using alternative tools and/or frameworks.